# Get substring of a complex string in php

Tags: php, string

I have the following string:

```
"@String RT @GetThisOne: Natio"
```

How can I get "GetThisOne" from this string?

Comment: You really need to expand on your problem statement.  Are you trying to get the name after RT?  Could there be more than one?  Etc.

Comment: You need to be more specific... will the position of your text change from string to string? What you want is probably going to be a regular expression...

Comment: Do you mean taht you want to extract "GetThisOne" from a string ?
Do you mean tou need to extract the string between `@` and `:` ?

What have you try so far ? What doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like this:

```
<?php

$string = "@String RT @GetThisOne: Natio";
preg_match('/@.*@([A-Za-z]*)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // outputs GetThisOne
```

Here, the pattern is the folowing: find an numeric string after the second `@`.
[Ideone example.](http://ideone.com/qMRY2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Find "@" position, and calculate position of ":" after the "@" found.

```
$at = strpos($string,'@');

substr($string,$at,strpos($string,':',$at)-$at);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try php explode function

```
$string = "@String RT @GetThisOne: Natio"

$arr = explode('@', $string);

if(is_array($arr) && count($arr)>0)
{
   echo $arr[0]."\n";
   echo $arr[1];
}
```

will echo out

String RT

GetThisOne: Natio